# Entity Framework edit and add error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую UnitOfWork Repositories

Модели

```
public class UTaskModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCrt  { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFinish { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCncl { get; set; }
    public string UserCncl { get; set;
    public string UserCtrl { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UTaskTargetModel> UTaskTargets { get; set; }
}
public class UTaskTargetModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UTaskId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCmpl  { get; set; }
}
```

По задаче планируется UTask

Создаю запись в бд

```
public void Create(UTask utask)
{
    db.UTasks.add(utask)
}
```

через период, завтра, послезавтра в UTask добавляются цели

Выбираю по ID UTask и добавляю UTaskTargets

добавляю и обновляю

```
    public void UpdateUTask(UTaskDTO data)
    {
        var item = Database.UTasks.Find(f => f.Id == data.Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            AddTargets(data.UTaskTargets);

            Database.UTasks.Update(Mapper.Map<UTaskDTO, UTaskModel>(data));
            Database.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ValidationException("UTask not exist", "");
        }
    }
```

UTaskTargets добавились, 
после хочу обновить в UTask DateFinish = DateTime.Now

```
    public void Update(UTaskModel item)
    {
        db.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Выбивает ошибку

```
        Не удалось присоединить сущность типа &quot;NDashApp.DAL.Entities.Feedback.FeedbackModel&quot;, 
    поскольку другая сущность этого же типа уже имеет такое же значение первичного ключа. 
Такое возможно при использовании метода &quot;Attach&quot; 
    или задании сущности состояния &quot;Unchanged&quot; или &quot;Modified&quot;,
 если какие-либо сущности в графе имеют конфликтующие значения ключей. 
    Такое возможно из-за того, что некоторые сущности являются новыми и 
    пока еще не получили значения ключей, сформированные базой данных. 
    В этом случае используйте метод &quot;Add&quot; или состояние сущности 
&quot;Added&quot; для отслеживания графа, а затем задайте сущностям, 
    которые не являются новыми, состояние &quot;Unchanged&quot; или &quot;Modified&quot;.
```

Перепробовал многое, не получается обновить DateFinish.

Как обновить DateFinish в UTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё потому, что DbContext отслеживает изменения всех материализованных в данном сеансе сущностей и если вы специально не отсоединяли сущность от контекста, то и не надо её присоединять. Просто поменяйте нужное поле и вызовите SaveChanges().

А ещё лучше сделайте все изменения во всех нужных сущностях и только потом делайте SaveChanges(). Это как раз и есть концепция Entity Framework, он реализует патерн единица работы, меняете всё что вам нужно и в конце применяете всё одной транзакцией.

Ещё по вашему коду я не увидел правильного применения DdContext. На всякий случай пример:

```
using(var db = new DbContext())
{
    // здесь все манипуляции
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Суть простая, делаете как можно коротко живущий DbContext.

p.s.
Вместо DbContext соответственно ваш класс наследник.

Comment: Время жизни DbContext влияет на производительность?

Comment: Первое создание DbContext прогревает кеши модели, последующие уже не влияют на производительность. DbContext отслеживает состояния всех запрашиваемых сущностей и чем дольше он открыт тем больше сущностей он кеширует и тем больше он потребляет памяти. Для веб лучше уничтожать его как можно быстрее, для десктоп приложений можно оставлять открытым и ипользовать как кеш, но нужно понимать что вы делаете. Для сценария когда нужно только получить данные из базы можно использовать расширение .AsNoTracking(), в этом случае материализация будет происходить быстрее и DbContext будет работать как прокси.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!)